# Adding a VLAN to Multiple Aliased (Virtual) Interfaces

Tags: linux, centos, linux-networking, vlan, alias

I have a server running centOS 4.6 with 4 NIC ports.  I successfully set up 2 ports with 32 virtual interfaces to handle my VLAN-untagged connections and have no issues with that side of things.  However, I need to add an identical capacity on the VLAN 2082 network using the remaining 2 ports.

I used NAT to connect the 10.2.80.X networks and the 10.2.82.X network, which has worked great so far.  Now I'm just having problems with the combination of aliased interfaces AND assigning VLAN's to them.

[NETWORK DIAGRAM](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4xz095gexae60ho/Network%20Changes%20with%20VLAN.jpg?dl=0)

I tried adding VLAN's to the virtual interfaces the same way I did before.  I did:

```
[root@blah]# vconfig add lan1 2082
Added VLAN with VID == 2082 to IF -:lan1:-
```

When I tried with the virtual/aliased interface:

```
[root@blah]# vconfig add lan1:1 2082
ERROR: trying to add VLAN #2082 to IF -:lan1:1:-  error: Invalid argument
```

I also tried:

```
[root@blah]# ip link set link lan1:1 name lan1:1.2082 type vlan id 2082
Error: either "dev" is duplicate, or "lan1:1" is a garbage.
```

I ensured the interfaces were up with

```
ifup lan1:1
ifup lan1
```

And this is the ifconfig status:

```
lan1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1B:21:32:5D:CB
          inet addr:10.2.80.253  Bcast:10.2.80.255  Mask:255.255.255.252
          inet6 addr: fe80::21b:21ff:fe32:5dcb/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:19915 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:195 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1672181 (1.5 MiB)  TX bytes:14684 (14.3 KiB)
          Base address:0x4040 Memory:e80a0000-e80c0000

lan1:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1B:21:32:5D:CB
          inet addr:10.2.80.193  Bcast:10.2.80.195  Mask:255.255.255.252
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Base address:0x4040 Memory:e80a0000-e80c0000
```

One forum I stumbled on hinted that this might not be possible with CentOS 4.6, although others had some solutions that I couldn't get to work.  Hopefully y'all can be a bit more authoritative on the subject.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An aliased interface is really just a secondary address on the original interface the alias was created from (see how there are no packet counters for `lan1:1`). As such you can't create VLAN sub-interfaces on it.

What you *can* do is create aliases or add secondary addresses to a VLAN interface.